# How to post the Theta 360 degree photo to facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, theta360

I am using the  [Theta Camera SDK](https://developers.theta360.com/en/docs/sdk/) to take the picture in 360 degrees.

I want to post this photo to Facebook this is 360 photo.

```
  String path=  "/storage/emulated/0/path/imagebitmap.jpg";

    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()

            .setImageUrl(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)))
            .setCaption("")
            .build();

    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo)

            .build();
    ShareApi.share(content,shareCallback);
```

It was Successfully posted on facebook but view like that

[image]

I am changing the extension with ._er_injected but the same problem occurs.

Also Use this Code

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.imagebitmap);

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

    Bundle params = new Bundle();


    /*spherical_metadata*/
        String mjson="{\"ProjectionType\": \"equirectangular\",\"CroppedAreaImageWidthPixels\": 240,\"CroppedAreaImageHeightPixels\": 240,\"FullPanoWidthPixels\": 1962,\"FullPanoHeightPixels\": 981,\"CroppedAreaLeftPixels\": 981,\"CroppedAreaTopPixels\": 490}";

    params.putByteArray("picture", byteArray);
    params.putBoolean("allow_spherical_photo", true);
    params.putString("spherical_metadata", mjson);
    params.putString("name", "Panorama images");




 /* make the API call */


    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/photos",
            params,
            HttpMethod.POST,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        /* handle the result */

                    Log.e("@@@response", String.valueOf(response));
                //  Toast.makeText()


                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```

I think I am calling API in wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got the Solution by  [Read this Link](https://developers.google.com/streetview/spherical-metadata) and Call graph Api of Facebook

And more Read about this spherical from [This Facebook reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/)

Read Carefully about the ProjectionType, CroppedAreaImageWidthPixels etc from both links and changes made Accordingly

The Size is taken are the Same Size of Image which (5376*2688) so take the size according to Image width height

```
private void sharePhotoToFacebook(){

  Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.imagebitmap);

  ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
  byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

  Bundle params = new Bundle();


  JSONObject json= new JSONObject();
  try {
     json.put("ProjectionType", "equirectangular");
     json.put("CroppedAreaImageWidthPixels", 5376);
     json.put("CroppedAreaImageHeightPixels", 2688);
     json.put("FullPanoWidthPixels", 5376);
     json.put("FullPanoHeightPixels", 2688);
     json.put("CroppedAreaLeftPixels", 0);
     json.put("CroppedAreaTopPixels", 0);

  } catch (JSONException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
  }


  JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
  params.putByteArray("picture", byteArray);
  params.putBoolean("allow_spherical_photo", true);
  params.putString("spherical_metadata", json.toString());




  new GraphRequest(
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
        "/me/photos",
        params,
        HttpMethod.POST,
        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
           public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        /* handle the result */

              Log.e("@@@response", String.valueOf(response));

  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Snapshot shared On Facebook",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


           }
        }
  ).executeAsync();
 }
```